# Replacing the default JavaScript dialog box with a Bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have created a Bootstrap 3 modal that I would like to replace the default JavaScript dialog box. And the confirm button has to trigger a JavaScript action.

```html
<div id="credits" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header margin-b-25">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h6 class="modal-title">This is a modal</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body center">
      <p><b>modal</b></br>
        Do you want accept?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Go!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#unblock').click(function(){
    if(confirm('Are you sure that you want to accept?')){
      $('#mcd, #unblock, #unblock_whole').hide();
      $('#sendbtn, #quick_txt').show();
    }
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You should try : http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for a solution without something like bootboxjs

Comment: Then try something like this : https://gist.github.com/jnormore/7418776